# Argument 'myAction' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have this error:

> Argument 'myAction' is not a function, got undefined

This is my form (i don't want to use angular to post it).

```
<form method="post" action="MyAction.action">
```

This form is under an Angular controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-attr` to generate the content of the `action` attribute like this:

```
<form method="post" ng-attr-action="{{MyAction.action}}">
```